# i want to pass a path to an object

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to pass a path with the function to the constructor

```
this.elementImg.src = `${this.changeImage()}`;
```

Why this dont Work

```
changeImage = () => {
    if (this.speed < 6) {
        this.imagePaths[0];
    } else if (this.speed >= 6 && this.speed < 9) {
        this.imagePaths[1];
    } else if (this.speed >= 9) {
        this.imagePaths[2];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your function isn't returning anything. If you are thinking there is an implied `return` that is only for arrow functions that have no function body like: `()=>someValue`

Answer (score 1):

The function needs `return` statements.

Also, you don't need the `>=` tests, since the previous `<` test ensures that the value will be `>=` that value or it wouldn't go to `else`.

```
changeImage = () => {
    if (this.speed < 6) {
        return this.imagePaths[0];
    } else if this.speed < 9 {
        return this.imagePaths[1];
    } else {
        return this.imagePaths[2];
    }
}
```